# How to send key to specific program (js)?

Tags: jscript

New Question: I just started on js (JScript), and I'm starting easy out, I just run into this problem.. How do i make the "SendKey" send the key to a specific program, instead of just send the keys to the selected window?

This is my code so far:

```
        <package>
   <job id="js">
      <script language="JScript">
         var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
         WshShell.Run("cmd");
         WScript.Sleep(1000);
         WshShell.AppActivate("Windows Command Processor");
         WshShell.SendKeys ("echo hello");
      </script>
   </job>
</package>
```

Comment: Javascript is not Jscript.

Comment: So its JavaScript or Jscript?

Comment: The clue is in your tag: `<script language="JScript">`

Comment: FWIW JavaScript is the open web's standard scripting language. JScript is a Microsoft-proprietary dialect.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific example, you can specify the command to be run in the Command Prompt using [`cmd`'s command-line arguments](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html):

```js
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
// Use /c to close the Command Prompt window after running the command,
// or /k to keep it
WshShell.Run("cmd /c echo hello");
```

For general-purpose GUI automation, I'd recommend using tools like [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com). Windows Script Host's GUI automation capabilities are limited to `AppActivate` and `SendKeys` and are very unreliable.